# "She is speaking" vs. "I am speaking"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, telephone

> Tom: "Hi this is Tom, May I speak with Linda please?"
>   Linda: "Yes, she is speaking"

Can Linda say "yes, she is speaking" or does she have to say "yes, I am speaking"?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is not usual for Linda to say, "Yes, she is speaking." Instead, it would be more common for her to say, "Yes, this is Linda," or "Yes, I am Linda," or "Yes, Linda speaking," or simply "Yes, speaking."

Comment: Or simply "Speaking."

Comment: Or “This is she”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, but you'd definitely sound a bit old fashioned, don't you think?

Comment: Or, if you're trying for a less formal impression, "That's me."